# how to call api of application which is registered as keycloak

Tags: python, keycloak

I have registered my application A in keycloak. So when I try to access application A it redirects to the keycloak server after entering the correct credentials I'm able to access application A.

But how to access the application A API's using python code or any scripting language.

If tried using http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/lsac/protocol/openid-connect/token and get the access_token but how to proceed further?

Whenever I try to hit application A API it returns the login HTML of the keycloak server? So How can I access the application A API?